# WPF DataGrid control: adding the most recent row on top

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to programmatically add a row to the top in a DataGrid control. Any ideas?

Comment: I didn't realize that there was a DataGrid control shipped with WPF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insert the new row at the start of the list (that means the list that the grid is binding to.), i.e `myList.Insert(0, myobject);` If that doesn't work then you have binding issues, which should be a new question.